# http proxy setting does not present in salt-minion older versions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, salt-stack

It seems that http proxy setting in salt-minion does not support in salt-minion older version. Do we have any workaround for this.

When I am running salt command from salt-master, environment variables set in salt minion do not work.I have my http proxy setting in environment variables.but when i am running command from salt-master it does not get variables set in env.

Please let me know if any workaround for this. 
Salt minion version: 0.17.5

Answer (score 0):

You should set it permanently, and system wide (all users, all processes) add set variable in /etc/environment:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/environment
```

This file only accepts variable assignments like:

```
HTTP_PROXY="my value"
```

Do not use the export keyword here.
You need to logout from current user and login again so environment variables changes take place.

Comment: Still no luck. When I am running salt-call from minion its running without an error. But when running from salt-master, minion is not able to connect to internet.